# Excel pop out application inputbox ( search function )

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

i am trying to create a pop out box to search for a certain value on the 2nd column, as i am still new to vba coding, i could only do this much through googling.

What i'm trying to do was (all these were to be done in macro), to find a certain value, and then when the program found the certain value, it will copy the entire row where the value was  and paste it into a new sheet in excel ( with the same header )

this is the code that i have so far.

```
Sub macrotest()
x = 2
Do While Cells(x, 1) <> ""
If Cells(x, 2) = "TEST" Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(x).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(erow)
End If
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
x = x + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

[image]

as you can see from above, i'm trying to copy the circled row into a new sheet.

Comment: Why not use autofilter? See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s)

Comment: As Siddharth said, This could easily be achieved through AutoFilter. No need to go for VBA.

Comment: @SiddharthRout i have seen their program, but it doesn't still answer to my question, what they have done in their codes is that, they have set the variable to the value/string they wanted to search in VBA, but i wanted to do it on excel, like an input box for me to search whatever i want , not by editing the codes to search what i wanted. Thanks..

Comment: I know that :) Your input box can pass that text to the code which is mentioned in that link :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout My apologies, as i am still new to vba, may i know which line is the one that pass the text to the code? thanks.

Comment: No worries. I have posted the code below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments above, you can use `Autofilter` to do it. Unlike in the code which is mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s), you can use the `InputBox` to get the search text

In that link `strSearch = "Clarke, Matthew"` is hard coded. Now you can use the below code to get your own `strSearch`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim strSearch

    strSearch = Application.InputBox("Please enter the search string")

    If strSearch <> False And Len(Trim(strSearch)) <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print strSearch

        '
        '~~> Rest of the code
        '
    End If
End Sub
```